# applying lambda to tz-aware timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pytz

I have a pandas dataframe (named s) and one of the columns (date) is a TimeStamp

```
s.date[0]
Out[126]:
Timestamp('2014-01-28 00:52:00-0500', tz='dateutil//usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York')
```

At some point in the code I need to select a subset of s (using idx, a list of booleans). The output is:

```
s.date[idx]
Out[125]:
1019    2014-12-01 00:52:00-05:00
1020    2014-12-01 01:52:00-05:00
1021    2014-12-01 02:52:00-05:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns, tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York')]
```

Since I'm only interested in the hour, I thought I could just do:

```
s.date.hour
```

but of course, I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

Thinking that one can do:

```
s.date[0].hour
Out[128]: 0
```

I said, let me use a lambda to apply the .hour to every "row". Thus:

```
    s.date[idx].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
Out[129]:
1019      5
1020      6
1021      7
```

As you can see, I am not getting the time in "Eastern Time", but rather in UTC.

I've done some searching online, but nothing...
Is there a way to get the non-UTC hour?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `.dt` accessor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pandas 0.16.2, I didn't have a problem getting local US Eastern time from tz aware timestamps.

```
s = pd.Series(pd.date_range('20130101 09:10:12', periods=4, tz='US/Eastern', freq='H'))

>>> s
0    2013-01-01 09:10:12-05:00
1    2013-01-01 10:10:12-05:00
2    2013-01-01 11:10:12-05:00
3    2013-01-01 12:10:12-05:00
dtype: object

>>> s.dt.hour
0     9
1    10
2    11
3    12
dtype: int64
```

It also worked fine with indexing.

```
idx = [1, 3]
>>> s.ix[idx].dt.hour
1    10
3    12
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Interesting...
I knew about the dt command but it wasn't working. It turns out that when making the time tz-aware by using 'America/New York', the dt does not work. If I, on the other hand, use  'EST', it works. Is that the expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

Use the .dt accessor.

Documentation:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor